# Is it possible to get MAC address of a website?

Tags: networking, mac-address

I work on windows and was trying some network commands on CMD. I came across MAC addresses and was wondering if it is possible to get the MAC address of a website.

I tried `nslookup` but it gave me the IP address of the website.

I don't think it is possible to get MAC address of a website but correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You cannot query the MAC address as this is only known to the next switch/router.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?  Knowing the MAC address of a device isn’t very helpful

Answer (score 3):

### Nope.

#### You can’t do that.

You state:

> “I don't think it is possible to get MAC address of a website but correct me if I am wrong.”

No disrespect but you are correct about being wrong here: MAC addresses are only available on LANs [as explained in this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3454887):

> “The MAC address, by TCP/IP standards, is never communicated outside of the local-area network to which it pertains — routers beyond that LAN don't even get the information you're trying to record.”

And as further explained in this [Network Engineering SE site answer as well](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/3330/4719):

> “MAC addresses and IP addresses operate on different layers of the [internet protocol suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite). MAC addresses are used to identify machines within the same broadcast network on layer 2, while IP addresses are used on layer 3 to identify machines throughout different networks.”

Answer (score 2):

MAC addresses aren't used on the Internet scale. MAC is only available in a single network segment, for example in your local network (LAN). It's not visible for users on the other side of your router. Similarly, a MAC address of any server connected to the Internet is not available to you because you're also on the other side of a router (a lot of routers actually).